# Create nodes in Modeshape

Tags: jboss-eap-6, modeshape

I'm trying to connect to a remote ModeShape repository via WebDav. I can successfully mount it using the Mac Finder but I'm missing on how to create nodes from within the Finder. I tried using the Eclipse ModeShape plugin which allows me to create a new Publishing Area, but how to add nodes?

In short, how do I actually store and retrieve data from the remote ModeShape repository that I've created.

Using ModeShape 3.2, and EAP 6.1

Answer (score 1):

You add nodes by using Finder (or any other app that works with the file system) to create sub subdirectories and/or create/copy files into the mounted directory.

The WebDAV service simply maps nodes to files and folders. Thus, it really works best when you're storing `nt:file` and `nt:folder` nodes in the repository, since that's a director one-for-one mapping. All other types of nodes get mapped into 'nt:folder' nodes, so any WebDAV view of such nodes don't have all of the properties of those other nodes.

Comment: Randall, whenever I try to copy/paste files in the mounted directory, I get zero byte files. It doesn't matter which file type I use. And I can't delete those files because it complains it is in use.